# Downloading Windows 7 HP Drivers (not through Windows Update)

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, printer, network-printer

We are setting up a print server with both x64 and x86 Windows 7 printer drivers.  The server is x64 and we are installing all the drivers with x64 drivers there.  Some of the x86 drivers need to be installed from a 32 bit PC.  When we add one of our printers as a network printer to the PC it grabs a generic driver.  When we try to change the driver it says it can't use Windows Update to find the driver because the device is not recognized so only the "Have disk" option is available.  On HPs website it says to get the drivers through Windows Update and doesn't allow you to download them.  Is there anyway around this?

Comment: What's the printer model?

Comment: HP LaserJet 9000 but we have other models as well.

Comment: download from here http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome?sp4ts.oid=28651&ac.admitted=1412071963976.876444892.492883150